# Django/PythonAnywhere -- Getting Error "Something went wrong :-("- Debugging Tips

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am new and learning Full Deployment walkthrough on python Anywhere, But getting the Error. I have tried all possible things which I could do to resolve it but I am stuck here.
where *supriya25* is my directory name

Error is:

```
**Something went wrong :-(**
Something went wrong while trying to load this website; please try again later.

If it is your site, you should check your logs to determine what the problem is.
There was an error loading your PythonAnywhere-hosted site. There may be a bug in your code.

Error code: Unhandled Exception

**Debugging tips**

-The first place to look is at your web app page to ensure that there are no errors indicated there.
-Next, check your site's server and error logs for any messages — you can view them here:
   -supriya25.pythonanywhere.com.error.log
   -supriya25.pythonanywhere.com.server.log
-You can find helpful tips on the PythonAnywhere help site:
  -There's an ImportError in the logs
  -"403 Forbidden" error or "Connection Refused" error in logs
  -Database connection errors
  -There are many more helpful guides on our Help pages
If you get completely stuck, then drop us a line at support@pythonanywhere.com, in the forums, or use the "Send feedback" link on the site, with the relevant lines from your logs
```

Please help me to resolve this Error.

Answer (score 0):

So that's your web app. In such case you should follow what the error message says about the debugging -- start with checking the error log for you web app: you'll find links to the logs in the Log section of the Web page while being logged into PythonAnywhere.  A tip: read logs from the bottom up, to get the most recent errors first.

Comment: thank you.. but  have tried this too.. but still could not able to resolve the error

Comment: What do you see there? (in the logs)